# Excel VBA Count files last modified before date

Tags: excel, vba, file, count, last-modified

I am looking for some code that COUNTS the number of files in a specific folder, which have a specific last modified date: today - 90.

I did work out code to count ALL files in a folder (which is part of what I want), but am stuck on the count when the files are older.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

```
Sub CountFiles()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Set the paths
Dim PathEvaluations As String
Dim PathPDF As String
Dim PathA As String
Dim PathB As String

Dim CountEvaluations As Integer
Dim CountOldEvals As Integer
Dim CountPDF As Integer
Dim CountOldPDF As Integer

Dim MsgBoxTitle As String
Dim PurgeDate As Date

PathEvaluations = Worksheets("References").Range("B50").Value
PathPDF = Worksheets("References").Range("B51").Value
MsgBoxTitle = Worksheets("References").Range("B32").Value
PurgeDate = Worksheets("References").Range("B77").Value

    PathA = PathEvaluations & "*.xlsx"
    Filename = Dir(PathA)

    Do While Filename <> ""
        CountEvaluations = CountEvaluations + 1
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    PathB = PathPDF & "*.pdf"
    Filename = Dir(PathB)

    Do While Filename <> ""
        CountPDF = CountPDF + 1
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

MsgBox "System maintenance:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    CountEvaluations & " files found in: evaluations folder" & vbNewLine & _
    "of which " & CountOldEvals & " are from before: " & PurgeDate & " and can be deleted!" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
    CountPDF & " files found in: pdf folder" & vbNewLine & _
    "of which " & CountOldPDF & " are from before: " & PurgeDate & " and can be deleted!", vbInformation, MsgBoxTitle


End Sub
```

Comment: Can you use FileDateTime( FILEPATH )?  That should return the datetime in the local PC timezone of when it was created/last modified

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should work:

```
Dim FileDate As Date
Dim Minus90 As Date
Minus90 = DateAdd("d", -90, Date)

PathA = PathEvaluations & "*.xlsx"
    Filename = Dir(PathA)


    Do While Filename <> ""
        CountEvaluations = CountEvaluations + 1
        FileDate = FileDateTime(PathEvaluations & Filename)
        If FileDate <= Minus90 Then
        CountOldEvals = CountOldEvals + 1
        End If

        MsgBox (FileDate)
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop
```